# pattern tokenizer to token string like 222*abc**xyz******332434 as 222,abc,xyz,332434

Tags: regex, indexing, elasticsearch, tokenize

I am struggling to construct an analyzer to break my string of types `222*abc**xyz******332434` as `222,abc,xyz,332434` tokens. The * can be replaced my any of the special characters. Do i need to add any filters apart from providing regex patten?

Comment: make title short and sweet. Add extra info in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(\W+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/kH4bG4/1)**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestions,seems like this will work for me.Will try this on my dev machine when i will be back in office.

Comment: @user3775217 if this answered to your question you may consider marking your question as solved :)

Answer (score 1):

If "any of the special characters" is non-alphanumerics, you can make a simple pattern-tokenizer on `\W`.

Runnable example to play with here: https://found.no/play/gist/8b2d6dc03731c1e2daef#analysis

```
export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

curl -XPUT "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/index_name" -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "myAnalyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "specials"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "specials": {
                    "type": "pattern",
                    "pattern": "\\W"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {}
}'
```

Comment: thanks for suggestions,will try this on my dev machine

Comment: works great for me,except for the single .(period) it is not tokenizing.